# How do I avoid printing duplicate name from database using jsp?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, collections

I am having a database like this:

```
Student name| subject|subject code 
Ali         | java   | 5263
Ali         | php    | 9566
```

while displaying I just want Ali to be printed once.I   am using Collection Frameworks, but still not getting the expected output .

following is my code:

```
<%     Student_fetch  namesDAO = new Student_fetch ();
List<Student> all_names = namesDAO.getDetails(); 
   for( Students s1  :all_names) {  


    out.println(s1.getStud_name());
    out.println(s1.getStud_subject());
    out.println(s1.getStud_code());
      }
      %>
```

Please help me..

Comment: Can you please post the code so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: How are you going to chose which Ali is to be printed ?

Comment: I want Ali to be just printed once but both the subject and code should be printed is my condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended to use ['java.util.Set'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

```
<% Student_fetch  namesDAO = new Student_fetch ();
 Set<Student> all_names = namesDAO.getDetails(); 
   for( Students s1  :all_names) {  
    out.println(s1.getStud_name());
    out.println(s1.getStud_subject());
    out.println(s1.getStud_code());
   }
%>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me

Comment: @learningjava if this is the answer you were looking for, please accept answer because maybe someday, someone will be looking for same answer as you

Answer (score 0):

Store the Names in an array and make a check in that array. If the value repeats, display it once else just display